# Prop Type not being recognized?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hello I am having some issues with react and typescript project where I am trying to pass down a prop but for some reason it's not getting recognized with the appropriate type. I will attach some screenshots

If I put in any type for the props it works but when I inspect, the shape of the data is how I annotated in my interface (I think). What am I missing here?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8g8h.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gI5Dk.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LxH1.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAzI2.png

Comment: Could you please attach the Palette component code as well

Comment: generatePallete doesn't return the correct type, its missing properties

Answer (score 0):

Here is my palette component.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXrCj.png

Also here is my repo, probably would be a lot easier :)

https://github.com/Dan-Y-Ko/color_palette_react